# New to high->low poly baking why are my maps not lining up as expected?

Tags: workflow, texture-baking

So long story short, I'm trying to make a high poly from a low poly, add textures & materials to it, and then bake it out on the low poly for applying Normal/Diffuse/AO/Emission maps to an existing item (model) in a game called Rust (built in Unity).

As a test, I took the default cube, added a torus to it's top face and joined it (CTL-J).  I then baked a normal map and a diffuse texture.  While close, it's not quite right as some of the extra faces I've applied a material are not coming through.  Everything else is looking good-ish.  I'm getting my normals close.

My question is, and I have an associated blend file, what am I doing wrong as the diffuse map doesn't include all of the faces? I have in the high poly when baked to low poly.

These are default meshes from blender, so the UV's have been set, though I did unwrap the low poly cube via smart UV project.

As you can see, the low poly diffuse is short a few faces and the normal doesn't *quite* get everything.  It's like I'm off by a little.  Should I not use cage?  I'm not sure what's wrong with my process.

So the money question is, how do I get the same results from my high-poly to line up with the low-poly.  (Note: this is for a game asset in Unity that I don't have the liberty of modifying).

Should I be using a cage here?  Or setting the max ray distance to 1m?  Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Still new and learning, thanks for your time.

P.S. I do know that usually you make a low poly from high poly, but in this case, I can't modify the low poly and I'm trying to fake lighting via maps, and applying textures and materials for diffuse and emission.  Just not sure what to do here?

High poly with some faces set with a different base color material:
[image]

Here's the low-poly with normal from high->low bake applied as well as the diffuse providing the color data to the principled shader:
[image]

Here's the blend file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/a396643f5e84404ba32f8e1837d5ea43

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cage

Not in depth explanation, but if you change *Max Ray Distance* you can see it results in circles, so it looks a Cage Normal direction is calculated something like an average of two faces and not directly the face one.

[image]

### Without Cage

In this specific situation is better do not use the Cage, so the rays are shot in direction of Normal. Use simply *Selected to Active* and adjust **Extrusion** value like 0.3

[image]

[image]

Probably better [explanation here](https://youtu.be/kGszEIT4Kww?t=1033)

[image]

### Or...

Usually to bake this kind of normals (shapes on a flat surface), you go to Bake on Plane (placed above).

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, I understand.  I wasn't aware that cage was taking the average of two normals but that makes sense.  In this test case, I was using a simple cube, although I am trying to test a process for modifying a more complex shape and using *some* method of baking highpoly to lowpoly textures (normals/AO/diffuse/emission).  I do not believe I could use a plane in that case to encompass the entire object.  Do you have any thoughts on which approach would be best to do a full 360 degree projection from high to low poly to avoid the issue of having averaged normals?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I hear you there :) that we do.  Thank you very much for your input, it has given me some good ideas

Comment: One simple way to fix this issue without a cage is to add one or two subdivisions to a cube like this. Not that much more geo and it would dramatically improve the end result. I know this is just a test, but it's not at all uncommon to add a bit of geo in key areas to ensure a clean bake.

Comment: @vklidu - thank you! looking at the normals you baked it looks perfect without cage using extrude 0.3m - thank you very much :)

Comment: @Jakemoyo - thank you for the additional information, it makes total sense that I will get better normals with more faces (since I'm baking wo modifying the underlying mesh, you know I'm going ham w polys ;) haha), you are certainly correct this is merely a test but your info helps me going forward with my project fully so thank you very much!

Comment: @Jakemoyo Can you share your file? For me just subdividing has no difference. Thank you

Comment: check out this [post](https://polycount.com/discussion/147227/skew-you-buddy-making-sense-of-skewed-normal-map-details) to see what I'm talking about. The approach I suggested might not make sense in every scenario, but this goes way more in depth into problems regarding skewed normal map details that I ever could.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Thanks for the link, very nicely explained. But your comment to solve issue without cage by adding topo is not a true from my understanding. First if you don't use cage you don't have skewing issue, so there is not a reason to add topo. Second, to add topo was my first try that sound to me reasonable, exactly as Cube number 2, but with zero effect. That is why I asked you if you tried it in blender, so I can know if it is my wrong usage or blender doesn't works in the same way as 3d app used in your article. Thanks 

Comment: This issue is not an issue with Blender it's an issue with understanding how normal maps work on a fundamental level. The video you posted uses Maya to explain these concepts.  I'm not trying to "correct" you  by commenting, merely adding to your response by pointing out that sometimes skewed details can come from too little geometry to bake from in the low poly.

Comment: @Jakemoyo OK leave it, this discussion is not moving forward. Sorry if it is my wrong english causing misunderstanding ...

Comment: No worries bud! You answered it perfectly.